# Execute an existing jupyter notebook on an anaconda Virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have an existing Jupyter notebook and I need to execute it an anaconda environment. I add the conda environment to jupyter notebook by executing the following commands:

```
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv
```

Now, I can create a new jupyter notebook under the conda `myenv`.
The problem is how to execute an existing jupyter notebook with `myenv`? I can do it by copying the content to a new one but is there any other method?

Answer (score 1):

We have just change the kernel under `kernel->change kernel`